# Go gmail api quickstart results in localhost refused to connect ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: go, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-go-client

I'm following the steps in [go quickstart gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go).

On the function `getTokenFromWeb`, pasting either the long url
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=abcdefg.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.readonly&state=state-token`

or

`http://localhost:8000`

results in

> This site can't be reached.  localhost refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[image: site can't be reached image]

Following the same quickstart but [for python](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) works flawlessly.

If I get the token via python and use it in Go quickstart, it also works.  So the issue is just on the token from web retrieval.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you are having is related to the removal of [oob](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html).  When that sample was originally created oob still worked.  So it would display a nice web page for you where you could copy the authorization code.

That no longer works so we are forced to use http://127.0.0.1 or localhost.  As your machine apparently does not have a web server running its displaying to you a 404 error.

However if you look in the URL bar you will find the authorization code you need in order to authorize your application.

The solution is to simply copy the code from the url bar.  If you want to fix the 404 your going to have to figure out how to start a web server in order to host the http://127.0.0.1 from.

The python sample does this by running a local server

```
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

Php can do it using something like this

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t examples/
```

Im not sure how that can be done with Go though.

Comment: For anyone that finds this, you don't need to find a way to run a webserver, you can copy the code from the URL and paste it into your terminal where you ran the file from.
It prompts you to enter it with `Go to the following link in your browser then type the authorization code:` and then has the link to go to.
Once you get to the `This site can't be reached`, the code you need to copy/paste into your terminal is in the URL.
\&code=<long-code-is-here-copy-this>=https://

Comment: This is true but a lot of developers find it messy as the browser displays a 404 error without the webserver running